# Not able to click on the Mobile element after adding wait method and accurate locator

Tags: android-studio, mobile, sdk, appium, nosuchelementexception

I tried my level best but when the mobile application is getting opened its taking fraction of second to update, already I have tried implicit wait, explicit wait, accessiblity I'd, xpath everything but I am getting failed everytime